# Disable linux mouse wheel click paste in QtCreator

Tags: linux, qt-creator, copy-paste, mousewheel

The hot desks in my company, have these mice that 50% of the time I scroll the wheel it produces a middle button click. In linux this is a paste. So when I'm scrolling up and down some source code in QtCreator I tend to unintentionally paste around pieces of text. Even if I'm painfully aware of this effect it still happens and it's driving me crazy. I was able to disconnect the middle button paste in VSCode by changing a [setting](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14610) editor.selectionClipboard. I'm trying to find similar setting in QtCreator but I can't. Is there any way to achieve this in QtCreator?

I don't want to disable this middle button system wide as this feature is very useful to paste pieces of code/text in the terminal, where I don't wheel scroll as much as in a source code editor.